# List calculating each archive folders in Exchange On-Prem

Tags: exchange-server

I am looking for assistance writing a script which will create a CSV file detailing the 250+ public folders in our on-prem exchange installation.

The output would be something like this:

Name of public folder, folder size, owner

Thank you in advance.

I have tried a combination of commands and am able to get what I need at the individual folder level but require a list containing every public folder.